# How to update ui based on error in resolving future in getx

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, flutter-futurebuilder

Can we access the error generated during resolving future in `GetxController` in `UI` the same way we can do in future with `snapshot.error`

When using Future builder we can do `snapshot.hasError` and then we can update the `UI` based on the error like:
image

```
Future<List<String> getNamesFromApi() async {
 // fetch from api
 // return result
}

...

FutureBuilder(
 future: getNamesFromApi(),
 builder: (context,snapshot) => 
  snapshot.hasError 
  ? Text("error reading data")
  : snapshot.hasData
    ? Text(snapshot.data[0])
    : SizedBox.shrink()
```

however in Getx when we resolve future inside the `MyController` and assign that to a variable in the controller like:

```
final List<String> name;
@override
onInit() async {
 name = await getNamesFromApi();
 update();
}
```

and then use that in ui like:

```
GetBuilder<MyController>(
 builder: (controller) => 
  controller.name != null 
  ? Text(controller.name[0]) 
  : SizedBox.shrink(),
)
```

here we have no way to know if the future resolved with an error. The value will just be null

Is there a way to do this in Getx without using a package for functional programming concepts such as either.